# UITableView differentiate swipe to delete and multiple rows selection

Tags: ios, uitableview, edit

I'm working with a UITableView, and want to support both the standard edit tools provided by Apple. So far, I can swipe on a cell to show the "delete" button, and tap an "edit" button on the top right to enter multi-rows editing mode. That's working fine.

Problem is, I want my tableView to act just like as the mail app does, which is "do nothing else than show the delete button" when entering editing mode with the swipe gesture, and "show a trashcan button (anywhere)" when entering multi-rows editing mode. I can't figure out how I can know which editing mode I'm in...

For example, I added the `setEditing` method, in which I hide the tab bar (just to check the behavior of my table):

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated 
{

    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = editing;
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing) {

        self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;

    } else {

        self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
    }

}
```

Right now, when I swipe on a cell, or when I hit the edit button, the tab bar is hidden, and goes back to normal afterwards. I would like to hide it only when I hit the edit button.

Where and how should I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not handing the sender over to the editing method, like this?

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated sender:(id)sender
{

    self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = editing;
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if (editing && [sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) 
    {
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;
    } 
    else 
    {
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
    }

}
```

Comment: It changes the whole editing mode behavior ! In my storyboard, my tableView allows only single selection during editing because that's the only way I can have both swipe and multi-rows editing. When I hit the edit button, I can't select multiple rows anymore. It now shows a red button on the left of the cell, which then shows the delete button on the cell when clicked... That's with no doubt because 'setEditing' is not called anymore. BTW, I do not call manually 'setEditing', so I guess adding the sender makes the method "unknown" by my table, right ? Should I call it myself somewhere ?